# Htmlagilitypack doesnt get nodes.

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I am using Htmlagilitypack in c#. But when i want to select images in a div at the url bottom, there are nothing found in selector. But i think i write right selector. 
Codes are in fiddle. Thanks.

https://dotnetfiddle.net/NNIC3X

```
    var url = "https://fotogaleri.haberler.com/unlu-sarkici-imaj-degistirdi-gorenler-gozlerine/"; 
    //I will get the images src values in .col-big div at this url. 
    var web = new HtmlWeb();
    var doc = web.Load(url);

    var htmlNodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='col-big']//*/img");  
    //i am selecting all images in div.col-big. But there is nothing. 

    foreach (var node in htmlNodes)
    {       
        Console.WriteLine(node.Attributes["src"].Value);
    }
```

Comment: use [SectorGadget](http://selectorgadget.com/) to get the appropriate xpath

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your xpath is wrong because there is no div-tag that has class-attribtue with the value 'col-big'. There is however a div-tag that has a class attribute with the value 'col-big pull-left'. So try.

```
            var htmlNodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='col-big pull-left']//*/img");
```